# Symfony 2 Security Component : use loadUserByUsername from controller

Tags: php, security, symfony

Is there a way to use

loadUserByUsername (method of UserProviderInterface implementation depending security config)

from a controller action via a service or something else clean ?

i do not use FOSUserBundle

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

As native EntityUserProvider is **abstract**, it not possible... But, if you define your method loadUserByUsername in your own public service and call it from EntityUserProvider, you can use it from any ContainerAware class.

Comment: Thanks @Pécé !
In fact i just need to use the security componenent behavior to retrieve a user from his username.

Comment: I've set many providers (chained) ... so i would like to keep the existing chainedprovider

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Symfony2 does not give direct access to user providers registered. One dirty way would be, parse `security.yml` in `load()` method of `DependencyInjection/BundleExtension.php` e.g

```
//DependencyInjection/BundleExtension.php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    //...
    //parse security.yml
    //create an array mapping each provider keys in the firewall to the providers 
    //set the array as global parameter using $container->setParameter('provider.mappings', $array)
}
```

And then in controller you can do

```
$mapping = $this->container->getParameter('provider.mappings');
$providerKey = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getProviderKey();
$user = $mapping[$providerKey]->loadUserByUsername('user_name');
```

Comment: Thanks @m2mdas , i'll try this and keep you in touch !